# How to make smaller ArcMap PDF for use in InDesign?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, pdf, layouts

I frequently build reports that incorporate ArcMap maps. The maps are all exported in PDF format.

I am finding that there are so many line segments in the map that importing them at times is almost impossible. They also bulk up the report file, ballooning its size.

What can the technician do to make the map file smaller since multiple layers are unnecessary in a print document?

Comment: Do you have any raster data in these pdfs? Like a base layer? Those bloat pdfs. Do you have quality/resolution limitations? Also, do you have Adobe Acrobat Standard or Professional? Map size flexibility (11x17 vs 8.5x11)?

Comment: Is the issue that you are exporting Layered PDFs?  If so, then try changing Layers and Attributes to None on the Advanced tab of the Options panel on Export Map.  If your export to PDF is accomplished using Python then there is an equivalent switch to suppress PDF Layering available there too.

Comment: You say there are many line segments in the map that importing them [the map?] is almost impossible. Do you know if the map you receive has a similar size (lxw here) as the space you have available in your PDF? Is it possible your technician could make a couple maps, each with a certain set of lines, instead? That doesn't really address the file size, but probably nice looking maps is a bigger priority?

Answer (score 1):

The technician could export an image (e.g. png) instead of a PDF file.

Given the way it loads (sort of in "chunks"), it looks like layers are in the PDF. Try what PolyGeo mentioned above (turn off Layers and Attributes when exporting, don't export of the Map Georeference Information, etc.).

Working with the ArcMap technician on other export formats could get what you want, too -- one can export from ArcMap into an SVG file, for example, or EPS... (Personally, I almost always use 300dpi pngs when I'm putting an image into a printed report. Never had one that complex yet, though.)

Comment: No layers.No raster data...just shapes and fills. When the pdf is changed to png or any rasterization is done, all sharpness is gone. Dotted lines are fuzzy as is text. You might want to look at this map to help me diagnose what is happening in GIS and why the files are so large. I mean, when you open the pdf map in Illustrator, each letter of a word is on its own layer! Try this map:                                         http://www.co.lancaster.pa.us/planning/lib/planning/greenscapes2009/maps/figure_30_-_lancaster_county_green_infrastructure_concept_map.pdf

Comment: Given the way it loads (sort of in "chunks"), it looks like layers are in the PDF. Try what PolyGeo mentioned above (turn off Layers and Attributes when exporting, don't export of the Map Georeference Information, etc.).

Working with the ArcMap technician on other export formats could get what you want, too -- one can export from ArcMap into an SVG file, for example, or EPS... (Personally, I almost always use 300dpi pngs when I'm putting an image into a printed report. Never had one that complex yet, though.)